# CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set. in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake

Is there anyone know this CMake build issue? I saw several similar question, but they are on Window

In my case,

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- CMake version: 3.11

When I write terminal below

`cmake -DROOT="/home/kyuhwanyeon/workspace/2000_CMSIS_ws/CMSIS_5"   -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/kyuhwanyeon/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/"   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/home/kyuhwanyeon/workspace/2000_CMSIS_ws/CMSIS_5/CMSIS/DSP/gcc.cmake"   -DARM_CPU="cortex-m7"   -G "Unix Makefiles" ..`

Then the result,

```
CMake Error at /home/kyuhwanyeon/workspace/2000_CMSIS_ws/CMSIS_5/CMSIS/DSP/gcc.cmake:61 (add_link_options):
  Unknown CMake command "add_link_options".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:94 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I already update build-essentials... But my Cmake doesn't find Unix Makefiles.

Comment: If you have **several errors**, then they should be handled **one by one**, in the **order** they appears. Your first error message is `Unknown CMake command "add_link_options"`, so exactly it should be noted in the title and in the question post. When you resolve this error, you could move to another one - `Make was unable to find a build program`... if that error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_link_options` command was not available in CMake 3.11.  You can read this version of the CMake manual here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-commands.7.html and see that it's not listed.

You'll need a newer version of CMake in order to build this software.

You should tell the author of the software that they should specify the correct minimum version of CMake their CMakeFile.txt file requires, so that the errors are more clear.  If they'd specified that they required CMake 3.13 (where this option was introduced) or better then you'd have received a message that you needed to upgrade CMake.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my CMake version as 3.17, then it is working